# Cannot push to an array with Node EventEmitter .on method

Tags: arrays, node.js, push, eventemitter

Using readLine to read from a file I have:

```
fs       = require 'fs'
readline = require 'readline'
stream   = require 'stream'

instream           = fs.createReadStream './test.txt'
outstream          = new stream
outstream.readable = true
outstream.writable = true

rl = readline.createInterface({input: instream, output: outstream, terminal: false})

arr = []

rl.on 'line', (line) ->
  arr.push line

console.log arr
```

I'm trying to push each line to an array, but the callback in `rl.on` doesn't seem to complete the `push()` method, but if I replace the `push` with `console.log` it will print every line of the file. I realise there are probably far better ways of achieving the same outcome, but this is an experiment that failed and I don't understand why.

Why is the `.on` callback not able to push the line to an array?

Comment: The issue isn't that the data isn't being pushed into the array, it's that you're logging the array before the data is pushed. The callback is asynchronous, and `console.log` is synchronous.

Comment: Do you mean that `console.log` is being called before the data is read from the file?

Comment: Indeed. If you want to log the array after the file has been read, put `console.log` inside of a `close` event handler for the readline interface.